# Remove category base from WordPress url only for specific category

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I would like to remove the category base from Wordpress URL only for specific category. 
For example, i need to change:
mysite.com/category/blog
to
mysite.com/blog

but i want to keep other categories unchanged:
mysite.com/category/songs

I think that it could be achieved with some .htaccess rule, but I found some generic rules that remove the basic category in all the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily achieve this by using Enhanced Custom Permalinks Wp plugin. you just need to go edit the category, yo will see a field to add your custom url.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-permalinks/

Comment: Any similar plugin for free?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with some custom filters & actions.
Try placing this code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "News" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $post->post_name .'-'. $post->ID .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %postname%-%post_id% struture
    $new_rules['^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

This will set up the permalink structure that you want for posts:

Comment: Can you do this without the post_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that without using plugins.
Through Admin panel
go to settings->permalinks and select default to custom

here you know more..
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: He wants to change only for specific category, not for all, please read the question

Comment: Oops sory another solution is in my  second  answer and more is here
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-permalink-for-one-category-only